# Program to roll 2 dice 36000 times with possibilities

Tags: c++, arrays, dice

I have a C++ homework to do, this is the question

```
//Dietel & Dietel C Programming //Chapter 6 Arrays: Page 241 Exercise:
6.19 /* Write a program that simulates the rolling of two dice. 

* The program should use rand to roll the first die, and 
* should use rand again to roll the second die. 

* The sum of the two values should then be calculated. (Note: Since each die 
* can show an integer value from 1 to 6, then the sum of the two values will vary
* from 2 to 12 with 7 being the most freqent sum and 2 and 12 being the least frequent
* sums.) Figure 6.23 shows the 36 possible combinations of the two dice. 

* Your program should
* roll the two dice 36,000 times. Use a single-scripted array to tally the numbers of times 
* each possible sum appears. 

* Print the results in a tabular format. Also, determine if the totals 
* are resonable; i.e there are six ways to roll a 7, so approximately one sixth of all of the
* rolls should be 7. 
*/
```

I created the program, but it gives me the output like this:

```
sum of Faces    Frequency
      2            0
      3         4041
      4            0
      5         7922
      6            0
      7        12154
      8            0
      9         7936
     10            0
     11         3948
     12            0
sum: 36001
```

I don't why it's giving 0 frequency for all even numbers

Here's what I coded so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    const int arraysize = 13;

    int counter[13], sum=0;
    // init counter
    for(int i=0; i<13; i++)
        counter[i] = 0;

    int die1; 
    int die2;

    for ( int roll1 = 0; roll1 <=36000; roll1++ ) {
        die1 =  1 + rand() % 6;
        die2 =  1 + rand() % 6;
        counter[die1+die2]++;
    }

    cout<<"sum of Faces"<<setw(13)<<"Frequency"<<endl;

    for(int face=2; face<arraysize;face++)
    {
        cout<<setw(7)<<face<<setw(13)<<counter[face]<<endl;
        sum += counter[face];
    }

    cout << "sum: " << sum;


    return 0;
}
```

I need to add possibilities for the dice as well, example:

```
1 + 1 = 2 : 1 possibility for sum to be 2
1 + 2 = 2 + 1 = 3 : 2 possibility for sum to be 3
1 + 3 = 2 + 2 = 3 + 1 = 4 : 3 possibility for sum to be 4
.
.
.
6 + 6 = 12 : 1 possibility for sum to be 12
```

Comment: Here come another homework, lets do this !! :D

Comment: `I don't why it's giving 0 frequency for all even numbers`  Why not?  Did you write the program?  If you did, debug your program to discover why the even numbers are not behaving correctly.

Comment: It looks like you might have a very poor implementation of `rand`. Try using the modern [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) library instead.

Comment: Try adding `srand(time(NULL))` at the start of your program,

Comment: `rand` implementation is bad, switching to different one would be helpful. Try [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) if it helps.

Comment: If you didn't copy and paste that code but retyped it, I would look for a typo where `die1` accidentally became `die2` or vice versa.

Comment: Better change `<=36000` to `<36000` for 36000 rolls instead of 36001 which your program does now.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I didn't add any strange code for even numbers, it should give frequency for all faces, right

Comment: @yahyaelfakir I added it after the int die1 and die2, nothing happens.

Comment: @molbdnilo Well, do you see a typo? Because I don't.

Comment: @moose You can be your own detective very easily.  Just output what the values are that you're using by adding two simple `cout` lines (the most elementary of debugging techniques -- outputting values).  If you would have simply outputted the values of `die1` and `die2`, you would have focused your question down to the `rand()` function not working properly.   Then your question could have been `my rand() function is not working correctly when I do this...` instead of `I don't know what's wrong with my program`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to be seeding the random function, this can produce strange results

Solution:

```
#include <ctime>   // time()
#include <cstdlib> // srand(), rand()

...

srand(time(NULL)); // There are better ways to seed rand(), but this is simple

...

for ( int roll1 = 0; roll1 <=36000; roll1++ ) {
    die1 =  1 + rand() % 6;
    die2 =  1 + rand() % 6;
    counter[die1+die2]++;
}
```

Also, if you want a more C++-like solution (and have access to C++11), [check this out](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)

Comment: Not seeding it won't give "strange" results; it will just give the same results for each program run. If the implementation is sufficiently broken that the default seed never gives two consecutive even numbers, then seeding it won't help.

Comment: @levi We are not allowed to use ctime or cstdlib. Do you have a solution which doesn't involve additional libs? Also what about the the possibilities?

Comment: @moose The rand() implementation you're using is broken, not your program.

Comment: @moose: If you can't use `<cstdlib>`, then you can't use `rand()` (your program must be including it by accident, when you include other library headers). If you're supposed to write your own pseudo-random number generator, then google will quickly tell you how.

Answer (score 2):

I just copy past your code and run it, you seem to lack library for rand function ( have no idea how you run yours ) anyways i just imported library for rand....

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    const int arraysize = 13;

    int counter[13], sum=0;
    // init counter
    for(int i=0; i<13; i++)
        counter[i] = 0;

    int die1; 
    int die2;

    for ( int roll1 = 0; roll1 <=36000; roll1++ ) {
        die1 =  1 + rand() % 6;
        die2 =  1 + rand() % 6;
        counter[die1+die2]++;
    }

    cout<<"sum of Faces"<<setw(13)<<"Frequency"<<endl;

    for(int face=2; face<arraysize;face++)
    {
        cout<<setw(7)<<face<<setw(13)<<counter[face]<<endl;
        sum += counter[face];
    }

    cout << "sum: " << sum;


    return 0;
}
```

It is running correctly in my machine.

Comment: This is exactly the same code, but with a non-standard header.

Comment: @yahyaelfakir Silly me! Tried it on Visual Studio, worked fine. Giving all frequencies for each faces. But I am thinking how do I add the possibilities like this: 1 + 1 = 2 : 1 possibility for sum to be 2
1 + 2 = 2 + 1 = 3 : 2 possibility for sum to be 3..... I am thinking I need to add another coutner/for for this?

Comment: hmm this is another question... yeah think you can do this with 2 loops going from 1 to 6 and storing the sum in an array of size 12.

Answer (score 1):

Let's play dice! The traditional die is a cube. Each of its six faces shows a different number of dots from 1 to 6. Dice are used to produce results from 1 through 6. When a die is thrown (or rolled) and the die comes to rest, the face of the die that is uppermost provides the value of the throw. If an unbiased die is thrown, each value from 1 to 6 is equally likely.

Your programming task is related to the analysis of sequences produced by rolling a die.

Create a program named Dice to solve the following exercises. The input of the program is a so-called trial, i.e. a sequence of the rolled results. This input must be read from the standard input. The first line of the input contains a single integer N, indicating the number of throws \left(1\le N:\le1000000\right). The second line of the input contains exactly N characters, each character is a digit from 1 to 6. For example, the input can be as follows:

8
32646135
The output of the program should be written to the standard output. There are 3 exercises you are expected to solve. The output should contain exactly 3 lines: the ith line in the output is the solution to exercise i.

---

Exercises
Exercise 1
How many times did it occur in the trial, that exactly two 6s were rolled after each other? For example, in sequence 56611166626634416 it occurred twice, that exactly two 6s were thrown after each other.

Exercise 2
Find the length of the longest subsequence of successive rolls, in which the value 6 does not occur. (This number can be zero, if only 6s were thrown.) For example, in the trial 66423612345654 the longest subsequence of successive rolls in which the value 6 does not occur is 12345. Its length is 5.

Exercise 3
We shall call a sequence of successive rolls in the trial a lucky series, if the sequence contains only 5s and 6s. For example 6556665 is a lucky series, with a length of 7.
Find out, which is the most frequent length for lucky series. If there are more than one "most frequent" lucky series lengths, print the longest. If there are no lucky series in the trial, print zero.

Be aware. We are not interested in the most frequent lucky series. The four lucky series 656, 555, 556 and 666 are equivalent for us, all of them are lucky series of length three. We are looking for the most frequent length of lucky series.

For example, in trial 5533661656, the series 656 is the longest lucky series. But there is only one lucky series of lenght three in the trial. 55 and 66 are also lucky series. This is why the correct answer is 2. In trial 456116513656124566 both the lucky series with length of 2 and 3 occur twice, there is a tie between them. Now the length of the longest (that is 3) should be printed. Examples example1 and example2 are aimed to make this situation clear.

---

Examples
We provide three simple examples to clarify the exercises. Test your solution with other, larger examples as well!

Example 1
Sample input:

9
616161666
Sample output:

0
1
1
Example 2
Sample input:

18
456116513656124566
Sample output:

1
4
3
Example 3
Sample input:

17
56611166626634416
Sample output:

2
4
3